# K8s Spring unable to create native thread

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I face a problem when running Microservices on K8s.
Sometimes this error is shown

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
```

I was checking some config on the worker (all process running as root):  **ulimit -a**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 385975
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1048576
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

and **cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max**

```
771951
```

Memory is good

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          96517       35835       45218          10       15462       60126
Swap:             0           0
```

Limits on each process is unlimited.

```
cat /proc/440583/limits | grep processes
Max processes             unlimited             processes
```

I created a script to counting the number of thread and write to file

```
while true; do ps -eo nlwp | tail -n +2 | awk '{ num_threads += $1 } END { print num_threads }' >> test.txt; date >> test.txt; sleep 10; done &
```

this is the log at the time of the error

```
Mon Jun 21 13:18:48 2021
34323
Mon Jun 21 13:18:52 2021
34325
Mon Jun 21 13:18:58 2021
34324
Mon Jun 21 13:19:02 2021
11945
Mon Jun 21 13:19:10 2021
11979
```

(the error occurs in 13:18)

All Microservices have good heap usage.
It's seems ulimit or thread-max not working as expected.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Could you add further information? I would be interested in the following: How do you deploy it? Which Java Version are you using? How much req. mem and limit mem is set? Did you monitor the Heap and GC? What is the Max Heap? What Java Options did you set?

Comment: I use base image:  openjdk:11.0.5-jre-slim.  Here is Java options:  -Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -Dsun.net.http.retryPost=false -Dhttp.retryPost=false   . I use grafana to monitor all Microservices and Heap & GC is normal.  Heap usage ~ 21% and non-heap ~ 40%. GC < 4ms

Comment: Here is limit of Container:
 limits:
    memory: 4Gi
 requests:
    memory: 3Gi

Comment: Did you run the container somewhere else?

Comment: No, I have only 1 K8s cluster. All instance are running on this. This error maybe occur in some worker (not only one worker)

Comment: Did you setup the cluster by yourself?

Comment: yes, we did it.

Comment: Why aren't the timestamps in the log more or less 10 seconds apart?

Comment: Is your container running as root or is there any user definitions in Dockerfile or Kubernetes manifest? Try to exec into pod and use "whoami".

Comment: yes, @Roadowl every query this command it'll take some seconds to finish. So the duration do not extact 10s.

Comment: @AkinOzer All docker/k8s runtime and Container are running as root user. Dockerfile or K8s manifest dont config anything about user

Comment: If your app is Java 11 then you shouldn't need xmx and xms options(it auto resizes itself for the container now, not the host). Did you try it without them?

Comment: Really, I will try and let you known.